# Why do headers and footers inherit the current value of \spaceskip, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: spacing, header-footer, paragraphs, grouping

**Problem**:

I'm using a listings-like package to display source code in a paper.  The environment that the package defines uses `\spaceskip=\fontdimen2` to ensure that spaces all have the same width.

When a page break happens within that environment, the header and footer of the previous page inherit the space skip setting, and have much-too-wide spaces (MWE below):

[image: Bad header]

What causes this, and how can I prevent it?  If it's a bug in the definition of the environment that changes \spaceskip, how should it be fixed?

**MWE** (`spaceskip` set to a large value to accentuate the issue):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{This one does not.}{This header has wide spaces.}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\bgroup\footnotesize\spaceskip=10\fontdimen2\font%
a b c

d e f

g h i
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a header, the font settings that are in effect at the page break are what will be in effect in the page header. LaTeX brings things back to “normal” for the header by calling `\reset@font` which by default just calls `\normalfont`. You will need to do a bit of additional work since you're changing `\spaceskip` as well which wasn't anticipated by the LaTeX team to be something that would get modified mid-document.¹

The solution for your needs would be to restore the default `\spaceskip` as part of `\reset@font`. Something like this would do the job:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\defaultspaceskip}
\setlength{\defaultspaceskip}{\spaceskip}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\reset@font}{}
   {%
    \normalfont
    \setlength{\spaceskip}{\defaultspaceskip}%
   }
\makeatother
```

This would also fix some other possible issues, like if you had a footnote insie your environment with the modified `\spaceskip` since `\reset@font` is also called as part of setting the text of footnotes (both on a page and in a minipage) as well as when starting a float or a marginpar.

**Edited to add**

Another approach might be to just modify the appropriate `\fontdimen`(s) of the current font to have the desired spacing. I'm not sure how feasible that is for your particular application though.

---

1. In working on my LaTeX book, I got bit by a similar issue because I have two different definitions of `\normalfont` in my book depending on whether it's the main text of the book or it's example LaTeX output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use saveboxes.  They are formatted when created.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\leftmarkbox}
\newsavebox{\rightmarbox}
\savebox\leftmarkbox{Left header}
\savebox\rightmarkbox{Right header}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{\usebox\leftmarkbox}{\usebox\rightmarkbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\bgroup\footnotesize\spaceskip=10\fontdimen2\font%
a b c

d e f

g h i
\egroup
\end{document}
```